# Running header with nested generated content

Tags: css-paged-media, pdf-reactor

This is a question about Paged Media.
I want to mix a string-set with running elements. It works in PrinceXML but not in PDFReactor. My question, is this possible in PDFReactor?

HTML

```
<p class="head">
    <span class="first">Repeatable title</span>
    <span class="divider">|</span>
    <span class="last"></span>
</p>
```

CSS

```
p.head {
    position: running(heading);
    font-size: 8pt;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@page {
    size: A4;

    @top-left {
        content: element(heading);
    }
}
```

So far everything is peachy. But when I try to define a string-set from a H1 and try to write this into span.last this isn't working.

```
h1 {
    string-set: doctitle content();
}

p.head span.last {
    content: string(doctitle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with PDFreactor as well. Just the syntax is a bit different. PDFreactor does not support the `content()` function for the `string-set` property with Named Strings. Instead it uses the `self` value which works like `content()` or `content(text)` (see http://www.pdfreactor.com/product/doc_html/index.html#NamedStrings )

There is a second issue. You are setting the `content` property on the span element itself. Usually in CSS, creating generated content with the `content` property is actually only allowed for page margin boxes and pseudo elements such as `::before` and `::after`. This is also how browsers support it. Not sure why this works in Prince.

So basically you just have to make 2 minor adjustments to your style sheet to make this work in PDFreactor:

```css
h1 {
    string-set: doctitle self;
}

p.head span.last::before {
    content: string(doctitle);
}
```